# C++ Find and Replace in Hex

Tags: c++, hex

I simply want to :

1. Open a file
2. Search for a hex value
3. Replace it with another hex value
4. Save the file !

This is what I have tried but it seems that it's not working

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

void FindAndReplace(CHAR Before[], CHAR After[], int Size)
{
typedef std::istream_iterator<unsigned char> input_iter_t;
typedef std::ostream_iterator<unsigned char> output_iter_t;

std::fstream f("C:\\myfile.exe", std::ios::binary | std::ios::in | std::ios::out);

if (search(input_iter_t(f), input_iter_t(), Before, Before + Size) != input_iter_t()) {
    f.seekp(-Size, std::ios::cur);
    f.write(After, Size);
    }
}
```

And call it in this way

```
CHAR Before[] = {0x2D,0x43,0x89,0x5D};
CHAR After[] = {0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00};
FindAndReplace(Before,After,4);
```

Do you know any other way to do such a thing ? Or what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: What do you mean by "it's not working", exactly ?

Comment: _'but it seems that it's not working'_ Could you elaborate more, what exactly isn't working? Compile erros, unexpected results, program crash?

Comment: @PaulR Thats clear, even one byte of my file does not change

Comment: What happens when you step through the code in your debugger ? Does the code within the `if(...)` get executed ?

Comment: @g-makulik No, my program does not crash and I don't get any compile errors

Comment: @PaulR No :| , The codes within `if` don't get executed

Comment: OK - so that suggests that `search` is not working - maybe you should examine the parameters that you are passing to it ?